# some odd corruption issues

Tags: c++, corruption

Here's some snippets of a winamp plugin I've been modifying for outputting visual data over a serial port

```
char * overrideCom = NULL;
char * cPortName;

void config(struct winampVisModule *this_mod)
{
    MessageBox(this_mod->hwndParent, cPortName, "Serial Port", MB_OK); // Tell us what the value is
}

// This function will convert a System^ string into a std::string
std::string makeStd(String ^in){
    array<Byte, 1> ^chars = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(in);
    pin_ptr<Byte> charsPointer = &(chars[0]);
    char *nativeCharsPointer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(static_cast<unsigned char *>(charsPointer));
    std::string native(nativeCharsPointer, chars->Length);
    return nativeCharsPointer;
}

// This function will grab the second indexed com port and return it in an easily convertable std::string instead of String^
std::string getComPort(){
    array<String^, 1> ^serialPorts = nullptr;
    LPTSTR out;
    try {
        serialPorts = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
    }
    catch (Win32Exception^ ex)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to find COM port!","Initialize Failed!", MB_OK);
    }

    std::string portb = makeStd(serialPorts[1]);
    out = const_cast<char *>(portb.c_str());
    // Make sure I'm not crazy:
    MessageBox(NULL, out, "Com port!", MB_OK);
    return portb;
}

int init(struct winampVisModule *this_mod)
{
    config_read(this_mod);

    //std::string port = getComPort();
    //cPortName = const_cast<char *>(port.c_str());

    // This would normally work but for some reason causes corruption of the string and doesn't connect properly:

    if (overrideCom == NULL || overrideCom[0] == 0){
        std::string portx = getComPort();
        cPortName = const_cast<char *>(portx.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        cPortName = overrideCom;
    }

return 0;
}

void config_getinifn(struct winampVisModule *this_mod, char *ini_file)
{   // makes a .ini file in the winamp directory named "plugin.ini"
    char *p;
    GetModuleFileName(this_mod->hDllInstance,ini_file,MAX_PATH);
    p=ini_file+strlen(ini_file);
    while (p >= ini_file && *p != '\\') p--;
    if (++p >= ini_file) *p = 0;
    strcat(ini_file,"plugin.ini");
}


void config_read(struct winampVisModule *this_mod)
{
    char ini_file[MAX_PATH];
    char* tResult = new char[255];
    config_getinifn(this_mod,ini_file);
    config_x = GetPrivateProfileInt(this_mod->description,"Screen_x",config_x,ini_file);
    config_y = GetPrivateProfileInt(this_mod->description,"Screen_y",config_y,ini_file);
    // Grab the overrideCom= param.
    GetPrivateProfileString(this_mod->description, "overrideCom", NULL, tResult, 255, ini_file);
    overrideCom = tResult;
}
```

When I run the code without an overrideCom parameter, it is supposed to compensate by grabbing the 2nd indexed com port it can find, alone it works fine:

```
std::string port = getComPort();
cPortName = const_cast<char *>(port.c_str());
```

but this does not work:

```
if (overrideCom == NULL || overrideCom[0] == 0){
    std::string portx = getComPort();
    cPortName = const_cast<char *>(portx.c_str());
}
else
{
    cPortName = overrideCom;
}
```

The port does not connect and when I call config() I get a message box saying:

```
Èêtw
```

When I omit the above if statement, config() outputs:

```
COM3
```

I don't get it!

ALSO,
when an overrideCom parameter is specified in the INI file, it works perfectly.

My goal is to not rely on the INI file and allow for it to autodetect the 2nd com port, but allow for an override in the INI if needed.

---

**DOH! The solution was to declare portx as a global variable.**

Comment: Microsoft already provided a much better version of your `MakeStd` function -- `marshal_as`.  For example, by including the right header file, you can do `marshal_as<std::string>(dotnetString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string portx = getComPort();
cPortName = const_cast<char *>(portx.c_str());
```

And on the next line `portx` gets destroyed, and so does its data. So `cPortName` is just a dangling pointer pointing to nothing.